# Angular FormGroup.reset is triggering the ngSubmit event

Tags: html, angular, typescript

If I have a form like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="someForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submit(someForm)">    

stuff

<button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

...and the `reset` method is like this:

```
reset(){
    this.someForm.reset();
}
```

Then the `submit` method I have provided for `ngSubmit` gets called if I click the `Reset` button.  Why?

I see in the [API documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#reset-anchor):

`reset(value?: any, {onlySelf, emitEvent}?: {onlySelf?: boolean, emitEvent?: boolean}) : void`

...but `onlySelf` and `emitEvent` seem to be completely undocumented.  Is the `emitEvent` part triggering form submission?

Was this always this way?  Is there somewhere else I should be looking to see documentation that will explain `onlySelf` and `emitEvent`?  Why would someone want a form reset to submit the form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try specifying the type of the reset button. Otherwise, it may be defaulting to a submit button as well.

```
<button type="button" (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: That was it!  I was not looking in that direction at all - you've saved me a lot of time.  I'll accept your answer once the wait period expires...